# angular/compiler-cli package was not properly installed

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-compiler-cli

I am new in angular 2 and i have downloaded Angular2 project from server and try to run in my local environment after installing npm but it is showing the below error:

> The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error:
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Private' of undefined
>
> Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.
> Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Private' of undefined
>
> ```
> at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Aguila\Admin\Aguila_Admin\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js:14:11)
> at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
> at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
> at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
> at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Aguila\Admin\Aguila_Admin\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\eject.js:10:19)
> at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
> at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
> at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
> at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Aguila\Admin\Aguila_Admin\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\styles.js:6:17)
> at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
> ```

I am tring it from morning but nothing is working . Please answer as soon as possble. This is my project.json file:

```
{
  "name": "aguila-admin",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Content Management and Situation Administration for VR Trainer",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "build": "gulp",
    "start": "gulp && concurrently --kill-others \"gulp watch\" \"lite-server\"",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "author": "Jacob Kanipe-Illig",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-install": "^0.6.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.5.4",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-tslint": "^4.3.5",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.12.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.4",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.3",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
    "tslint": "^3.5.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.3.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: actually it is showing that my '@angular/compiler-cli' is not installed properly.. I have used npm `install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest ` command to restore node packages

Comment: Have you tried: npm install -g @angular/cli ? Also my friend was having this issue recently and she resolved it by installing angular first then the angular cli so npm install angular and then npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: yes i have done  the same way

Comment: What version of node are you using? node -v

Comment: i m using node:  v8.1.3 and npm: 5.0.3

Comment: It looks like your package.json is using some old versions for angular and typescript. Can you try updating to @angular 4? Also maybe try adding typescript to dependencies instead of devDependencies, could you try using typescript 2.4.2?

Comment: I have use `npm install -g  @angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.2` command for older version cli

Comment: ahh, sorry I don't know how to make that work with an older version. If your just getting started with angular I would suggest you go off of an angular 4 tutorial and just learn @latest. Good luck!

Comment: Ok Thanks i am tring the same with Angular 4

Comment: try angular cli